# Can't Find any of the add-ons on "Testing" for 2.8

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to find the import-export after effects add-on; the youtube tutorial I was watching said I should find it in the "Testing" section of the "add-on" menu. But Nothing shows up on my "Testing" section

Answer (score 1):

The **Testing** Add-ons are only shipped with the experimental buildbot releases, see [DevTalk](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/addons-contrib-folder-empty-in-recent-build/8556/2). This is even true if you would compile Blender yourself. Go to the [Download](https://www.blender.org/download/) section at blender.org and scroll down to the area where the experimental versions can be downloaded:

[image: experimental version]

Those builds should contain the Testing Add-ons you are looking for. If you want to use it in your 2.80 stable release too, you can simply extract it from the zip archive, and put it into the `scripts/addons_contrib` folder of your 2.80 installation, or your Blender user scripts directory:

[image: folder location]